# RecyclerView doesn't show data

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview, request

Its my first time when I'm trying to use RecyclerView. My app do request to get array of documents data. I wrote my own adapter for RecyclerView, TaskAsync class which extend from AsyncTask. And when do request all data which I need, but I don't know why those data doesn't show in my recycler view. pls help. I read many post about recyclerView, but I think in my adapter something goes wrong.

**Acts class and into this class I have TaskAsync**

```
public class Acts extends Fragment{

private String direction, limit, existingToken;
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private ArrayList<Document> documentsList;
private TextView docCategory;
private EditText search;

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private DocumentAdapter documentAdapter;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View act = inflater.inflate(R.layout.two_sided_docs, container, false);
    View header = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.document_list_header, null);
    docCategory = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.docs_category_one);
    search = (EditText)header.findViewById(R.id.search_text_one);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) act.findViewById(R.id.documentListView2);
    documentsList = new ArrayList<Document>();
    documentAdapter = new DocumentAdapter(act.getContext(), documentsList, Document.DOCUMENT_TYPE.ACT);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(act.getContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(documentAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    sharedPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences(Constants.PROJECT, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    existingToken = sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.TOKEN, "");
    direction = "in";
    limit = "50";
    new TestAsync(getActivity()).execute(Urls.ACTS_FEED);
    return act;
}

public class TestAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private Activity activity;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private OkHttpClient okHttpClient;
    private Request request;
    private RequestBody formBody;

    public TestAsync(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this.activity);
    }




    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        Log.i("sadasd", "asdasd");
        URL url;

        try {
            url = new URL(params[0]);

            okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();

            formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                    .add(Constants.DIRECTION, Constants.IN)
                    .add(Constants.LIMIT, Constants.docs_limit)
                    .build();

            request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url.toString())
                    .addHeader(Constants.AUTH_TOKEN, existingToken)
                    .post(formBody)
                    .build();

            Response response = null;
            response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
            return response.body().string();


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.i("test", "test1");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("test", "test2");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog.setTitle(R.string.wait);
        progressDialog.setMessage("load");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
        Log.i("test", "test3");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        Log.i("test", "test4" + s);
        AlertView.showAlertView(activity, Messages.CONNECTION_ERROR, s, Messages.OK);
        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        } else if (s == null) {
            Log.i("test", "test5");
            AlertView.showAlertView(activity, Messages.CONNECTION_ERROR, Messages.NO_INTERNET, Messages.OK);
        } else {
            Log.i("test", "test6");
            try {
                Log.i("test", "test7");
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                int code = Integer.valueOf(jsonObject.getString(Constants.CODE));
                if (code == Codes.OK) {
                    Log.i("test", "test8");
                    String header = jsonObject.getString("act_header");
                    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(header);

                    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonPart = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                        Document document = null;

                        String docId;
                        String docNum;
                        String docTotalPrice;
                        String senderCompany;
                        String receiverCompany;
                        BigInteger timestamp;
                        String docStatus;
                        String documentInternalType;

                        docId = jsonPart.getString("id");
                        docNum = jsonPart.getString("act_num");
                        docTotalPrice = jsonPart.getString("total_price");
                        senderCompany = jsonPart.getString("sender_company_name");
                        receiverCompany = jsonPart.getString("receiver_company_name");
                        timestamp = BigInteger.valueOf(Long.valueOf(jsonPart.getString("timestamp")));
                        docStatus = jsonPart.getString("status");
                        documentInternalType = jsonPart.getString("documentInternaltyep");

                        document = new Document(docId, docNum, docTotalPrice, senderCompany, receiverCompany, timestamp, docStatus, documentInternalType);
                        Log.i("document", document.toString());
                        documentsList.add(document);
                        documentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                } else {
                    Log.i("error", "error");
                    AlertView.showAlertView(activity, Messages.ERROR, jsonObject.getString(Constants.MESSAGE), Messages.OK);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                AlertView.showAlertView(activity, Messages.CONNECTION_ERROR, Messages.NO_INTERNET, Messages.OK);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

}

**And this is my DocumentAdapter class:**

```
public class DocumentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DocumentAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Document> docData;
private Document.DOCUMENT_TYPE documentType;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView datetime;
    TextView senderOrReceiverCompany;
    TextView docInfo;
    TextView docCost;
    ImageView arrow;
    TextView docStatus;

    ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);

        datetime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.datetime);
        senderOrReceiverCompany = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.senderc);
        docInfo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.docInfo);
        docCost = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cost);
        arrow = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.arrow_icon);
        docStatus = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.doc_st_sign);
    }
}

public DocumentAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Document> docData, Document.DOCUMENT_TYPE documentType) {
    this.context = context;
    this.docData = docData;
    this.documentType = documentType;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Context cn = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inf = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    View documentView = inf.inflate(R.layout.list_adapter_row, parent, false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(documentView);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return docData.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Document document = docData.get(position);

    TextView datetime;
    TextView senderOrReceiverCompany;
    TextView docInfo;
    TextView docCost;
    ImageView arrow;
    TextView docStatus;

    datetime = holder.datetime;
    datetime.setText(document.getTimestamp());

    senderOrReceiverCompany = holder.senderOrReceiverCompany;
    senderOrReceiverCompany.setText(document.getSenderCompany());

    docInfo = holder.docInfo;
    docInfo.setText(String.format(Constants.ACT_TITLE, document.getDocNum(), document.getTimestamp()));

    docCost = holder.docCost;

    docStatus = holder.docStatus;

    switch (documentType) {
        case ACT:
            docCost.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(Double.valueOf(document.getDocTotalPrice()))) + Constants.KZT);
            break;
        case SHIPPING_LIST:
            docCost.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(Double.valueOf(document.getDocTotalPrice()))) + Constants.KZT);
            break;
        case COMMON_DOCUMENT:
            docCost.setText("    ");
            break;
        case INVOICE:
            docCost.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(Double.valueOf(document.getDocTotalPrice()))) + Constants.KZT);
            String colorful = "";
            switch (document.getDocStatus()) {
                case "0":
                    colorful = Constants.DOCUMENT_INVOICE_STATUS.get(document.getDocStatus());
                    break;
                case "1":
                    colorful = "<font color='#008000'>" + Constants.DOCUMENT_INVOICE_STATUS.get(document.getDocStatus()) + "</font>";
                    break;
                case "2":
                    colorful = "<font color='#FFA500'>" + Constants.DOCUMENT_INVOICE_STATUS.get(document.getDocStatus()) + "</font>";
                    break;
                case "3":
                    colorful = "<font color='#EE0000'>" + Constants.DOCUMENT_INVOICE_STATUS.get(document.getDocStatus()) + "</font>";
                    break;
                default:
                    colorful = "<font color='#EE0000'>" + Constants.DOCUMENT_INVOICE_STATUS.get(document.getDocStatus()) + "</font>";
                    break;
            }
            docStatus.setText(Html.fromHtml(Constants.DOCUMENT_INVOICE_TYPE.get(document.getDocumentInternalType()) + " | " + colorful));
            break;
        case PAYMENT_INVOICE:
            docCost.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(Double.valueOf(document.getDocTotalPrice()))) + Constants.KZT);
            break;
        case RECON:
            docCost.setText("   ");
            break;
        default:
            docCost.setText(document.getDocTotalPrice());
            break;
    }

    if (!documentType.equals(Document.DOCUMENT_TYPE.INVOICE)) {
        switch (document.getDocStatus()) {
            case "1":
                docStatus.setText(Html.fromHtml(Constants.DOCUMENT_INTERNAL_TYPE.get(document.getDocumentInternalType()) + " | " + "<font color='#800080'>" + Constants.DOCUMENT_STATUS.get(document.getDocStatus()) + "</font>"));
                break;
            case "2":
                docStatus.setText(Html.fromHtml(Constants.DOCUMENT_INTERNAL_TYPE.get(document.getDocumentInternalType()) + " | " + "<font color='#800080'>" + Constants.DOCUMENT_STATUS.get(document.getDocStatus()) + "</font>"));
                break;
            case "3":
                docStatus.setText(Html.fromHtml(Constants.DOCUMENT_INTERNAL_TYPE.get(document.getDocumentInternalType()) + " | " + "<font color='#FFA500'>" + Constants.DOCUMENT_STATUS.get(document.getDocStatus()) + "</font>"));
                break;
            case "4":
                docStatus.setText(Html.fromHtml(Constants.DOCUMENT_INTERNAL_TYPE.get(document.getDocumentInternalType()) + " | " + "<font color='#008000'>" + Constants.DOCUMENT_STATUS.get(document.getDocStatus()) + "</font>"));
                break;
            case "6":
                docStatus.setText(Html.fromHtml(Constants.DOCUMENT_INTERNAL_TYPE.get(document.getDocumentInternalType()) + " | " + "<font color='#EE0000'>" + Constants.DOCUMENT_STATUS.get(document.getDocStatus()) + "</font>"));
                break;
            case "7":
                docStatus.setText(Html.fromHtml(Constants.DOCUMENT_INTERNAL_TYPE.get(document.getDocumentInternalType()) + " | " + "<font color='#EE0000'>" + Constants.DOCUMENT_STATUS.get(document.getDocStatus()) + "</font>"));
                break;
            default:
                docStatus.setText(Html.fromHtml(Constants.DOCUMENT_INTERNAL_TYPE.get(document.getDocumentInternalType()) + " | " + "<font color='#800080'>" + Constants.DOCUMENT_STATUS.get(document.getDocStatus()) + "</font>"));
                break;

        }

    }

    arrow = holder.arrow;
}

private Context getContext() {
    return context;
}
```

}

And this is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/documentListView2"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

**UPDATE**
this what I got after request:

```
test: test4{"code": 0, "act_header": [{"status": 1, "sender_company_name": "\u0422\u041e\u041e\"\u0410\u0441\u0435\u043c-2\"", "receiver_company_name": "\u0422\u041e\u041e\"\u0410\u0441\u0435\u043c-2\"", "total_price": "1.000000", "create_date": "10.05.2017", "descri...
```

and after `Log.i("test", "test4" + s)` nothing shows into android monitoring
I don't know why my data doesn't record

Comment: Do you have any data in your ArrayList<Document> docData? RecyclerView and adapter seems to be ok...

Answer (score 0):

Pass `getActivity()` as your Context in all the Fragment class. Try changing it like the following code.
This line:

```
documentAdapter = new DocumentAdapter(getActivity(), documentsList, Document.DOCUMENT_TYPE.ACT);
```

This line:

```
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
```

And this line:

```
sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Constants.PROJECT, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: it doesn't matter!

Comment: @MilosLulic changing getContext() to getActivity(). still not work

Comment: @MilosLulic and also before I wrote something like this, and used ListView and getContext and everything work perfect, and I think it doesn't depend on getActivity

Comment: Why is your View Holder class `static`?

Comment: @Xenolion how I said above it's my first time when I using RecyclerView and I just saw another post about recyclerView. Lets try to find some bugs in my Adapter :D

Comment: Trying removing static from ViewHolder

Comment: The problem here is we cant debug because we usually make adapters and View holders as inner class inside the Fragment or Activity. But you have sepated all in different classes.

Comment: Are you sure the data are loaded? and present? confirm that first!

Comment: @Xenolion after intering into onPostExecute into AsyncTask, Logger didn't show test6? may be problem was here ?

Comment: Yeah I am doubting my be the data are not there. But Recycler View Adapter looks Okay.

Comment: Okay @BakhtiyarBekbergen . Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with this line

```
documentAdapter = new DocumentAdapter(act.getContext(), documentsList, Document.DOCUMENT_TYPE.ACT);
```

Here, you are passing empty list which does not have any data. And in Adapter in getItemCount() method, you will get size as 0. so there is no data to display.

Try this.

In onPostExecute() method, after for loop where you parse your data call this line.

```
documentAdapter = new DocumentAdapter(act.getContext(), documentsList, Document.DOCUMENT_TYPE.ACT);
documentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

May be this will solve your issue.

Comment: No, problem not here) I solved this problem) but thanks that answer here :)

Comment: what was the issue??

Comment: look onPostExecute method

Answer (score 0):

In my case a problem was in assigning RecyclerView's `adapter` to itself.

```
private lateinit var adapter: MyAdapter

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_layout, container, false)

    val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    adapter = MyAdapter(listOf(MyAdapter.Item(1, "dfg")))
    view.recycler_view.apply {
        this.layoutManager = layoutManager
        this.adapter = adapter
        this.setHasFixedSize(true)
    }

    return view
}
```

After many hours I removed `apply` operator and understood that compiler recognized  `layoutManager` as local variable, while `adapter` was recognized as `recycler_view.adapter`.